# VSCode Chrome Debugger: Cannot watch any variables

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, frontend

I've installed the Chrome Debugger Extension for VS Code to debug my Angular project. Debugging itself works fine however I just cant watch any variables in the watch panel. It keeps saying "not available" even though they should be.

[image]

Comment: This is a guess, so I'm leaving it as a comment rather than an answer ... typescript renames "this" to "_this" when compiling, so does watching "_this.options" work for you?

Comment: Nope sorry this didnt work =/

Comment: Worth a try. Good luck!

Comment: do you have more code to show? In particular where your breakpoint is in relation to your watch? I am thinking it might be a scoping issue.

Comment: @Ekos I am having the same issue. Did you ever fix it?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Did you set any breakpoint in the code? In my case the WATCH field only shows the data if the data is also somewhere in the VARIABLES. Set a breakpoint at a point you can be sure your variable is set and check again.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: Maybe you post a bigger screenshot to see what you're doing? Your stack and stuff.

Comment: For me, all my members declared with @Input won't show up in the "Local" section, but under "Closures". In my "SliderComponent" I can access a member called "label" by adding the watch expression: "SliderComponent.propDecorators.label". I couldn't find the value though... Maybe you've got something similar.

Comment: this are really tricky in js world. Try putting explicit debugger and see if object exists?

Answer (score 2):

you have to set some breakpoints within some function call by double-clicking some line number; hit F5 to start debug mode, only then you can inspect the variables in that context/scope

[image]